# how to get the element Id from which jquery dialog is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery dialog for opening popup windows on button clicks.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen : false,
                height : 300,
                width : 350,
                modal : true,
                buttons : {
                    "Add" : function() {

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close : function() {
                    //if button1 is clicked 
                    alert("hello");
                   //if button2 is clicked
                   alert("bye");
                }
            });

        });
        function openWindow(){
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            }

    </script>
<button id="nameButton" onclick="openWindow()">click</button>
<button id="titleButton" onclick="openWindow()">click</button>
```

how to get the id of the button in the close method in jquery dialog?

Comment: Do not use "onclick" attribute on A elements. Bind the event using jquery and you can get the information from event object.

Comment: @ejzy what are you talking about...?

Comment: Second part of Kevin B's answer shows that pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use onclick attributes, you need to pass some information in to the function so that you can access the element that triggered the event.

```
<button id="nameButton" onclick="openWindow(this)">click</button>
<button id="titleButton" onclick="openWindow(this)">click</button>
```

---

```
function openWindow(button){
    alert(button.id);
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
}
```

Though, it would be *"better"* if you instead gave the buttons a class and bound the event with jQuery.

```
<button class="open-window" id="nameButton">click</button>
<button class="open-window" id="titleButton">click</button>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //... your existing code ...
    $(".open-window").click(function(){
        alert(this.id)
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Next, regardless of which of the two methods you used, you would need to store that data on the dialog.

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open").data("opener",this.id);
```

now you can access it with

```
$("#dialog-form").data("opener")
```

Comment: i want the id in the close function of the jquery dialog, not in the openWindow method

Comment: @vjk getting it into the click event is the first step of that. Next would be to store it somewhere, such as in the dialog's data.

Answer (score 0):

or u can use the **on** or **bind** or *click* event like:

```
$(#nameButton).bind('click', function(event){});
$(#nameButton).on('click', function(event){});
$(#nameButton).click(function(event){});
```

on **event** parameters u get all information that u need...

Comment: @ChenReuven He's suggesting that you correct the grammar, *"u"* -> "you"x3